# Boxplot missing label

Tags: r, boxplot

`boxplot(smkgp, nsmkgp, main="premature delivery", 
         xlab="gestation", ylim=c(200,400), xlim=c(0,3), 
         horizontal=TRUE, 
         names=c("smoking group", "nonsmoking group"))`

I'm making a box plot, and there are two groups to be displayed: Smoking group and non smoking group.

But label for non smoking group is missing.
I tried using par(mar(,,,,) to display the missing label but it didn't work.

How do I fix this problem?

I appreciate your time.

[image]

Comment: add `las = 1`; you'll probably also need to mess with the mar settings, try something like `par(mar = c(4,8,4,2))` (I increased the left margin to 8 lines)

Answer (score 2):

R won't print the second label because they would overlap. You might consider turning off the default yaxis (with `yaxt="n"`) and plotting the text and rotate the labels (with `axis()` and `las=2`). Be sure to add padding to the left margin to make room for the labels.

```
par(mar=c(5,10,4,2)+.1)
boxplot(runif(100),runif(100,.5,1.5), main="premature delivery", 
    xlab="gestation", xlim=c(0,3), 
    horizontal=TRUE, 
    yaxt="n"
)
axis(2, labels=c("smoking group", "nonsmoking group"), at=1:2, las=2)
```

[image]